# Python Pandas How to join 2 or more dataframes based on a similar column

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to join 2 or more dataframes together based on a column lets say 'id' The column has similar and different IDs but I want to join/merge/concat/append them together so they are all in one big dataframe.
Here is an example:

```
Df1:
id col1 col2
1  
2
4
5

Df2: 
id col3 col4
1
2
3
5
```

This is what I want:

```
Df3:
Id col1 col2 col3 col4
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)

Comment: Thank you! I wish I can mark this as the answer somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming no columns overlap other than the `id` column, you can merge them.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 4, 5], 'col1': list('ABCD'), 'col2': list('EFGH')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 5], 'col3': list('ABCD'), 'col4': list('EFGH')})

>>> df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='id').set_index('id').sort_index()
   col1 col2 col3 col4
id                    
1     A    E    A    E
2     B    F    B    F
3   NaN  NaN    C    G
4     C    G  NaN  NaN
5     D    H    D    H
```

Note that concatenation does not work given your example:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
  col1 col2  id col3 col4  id
0    A    E   1    A    E   1
1    B    F   2    B    F   2
2    C    G   4    C    G   3
3    D    H   5    D    H   5
```

You can merge the dataframes if you first set the index before using concat.  Here is a general solution for multiple dataframes:

```
dfs = (df1, df2)  # Add other dataframes as required.
>>> pd.concat([df.set_index('id') for df in dfs], axis=1)
   col1 col2 col3 col4
id                    
1     A    E    A    E
2     B    F    B    F
3   NaN  NaN    C    G
4     C    G  NaN  NaN
5     D    H    D    H
```

Note that if you have overlapping columns in your dataframe (e.g. `col2`), you would end up with something like this using `pd.concat`:

```
   col1 col2 col2 col4
id                    
1     A    E    A    E
2     B    F    B    F
3   NaN  NaN    C    G
4     C    G  NaN  NaN
5     D    H    D    H
```

Comment: oh interesting! Thanks for letting me know

Comment: But you can still concat, just set the index first?

Comment: @ALollz please explain

Comment: Yes, `pd.concat([df1.set_index('id'), df2.set_index('id')], axis=1)` works.